# StreamReader returning another char

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, stream, streamreader

I'm trying to read the content of a file with a StreamReader, that receives a FileStream. The file has some spaces inside (char 32) and the StreamReader is reading them as 0 (char 48). The screenshot shows the FileStream buffer and the StreamReader buffer. Both have the value 32, but when I call Read(), it returns 48. Am I missing something here? By the way, the code is running under .NET Compact Framework.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f72b61bbe.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f72b61bbe.png)

The code that reads the data:

```
public void Read() {
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(InputStream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
  foreach (var property in DataObject.EnumerateProperties()) {
   OffsetInfo offset = property.GetTextOffset();
   reader.BaseStream.Position = offset.Start - 1;
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(offset.Size);
   int count = 0;
   while (reader.Peek() >= 0 && count < offset.Size) {
    char c = (char)reader.Read();
    if ((int)c != 32 && c != '\r' && c != '\n')  {
     builder.Append(c);
     count++;
    } else {
     reader.BaseStream.Position++;
    }
   }
   property.SetValue(DataObject,
    Convert.ChangeType(builder.ToString(), property.PropertyType, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
    null
   );
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** Changing the encoding didn't worked (neither Unicode, nor Default)

**EDIT:** The input looks like this:

```
000636920000000532000404100100000001041000000001041000000001031000000000000000000000000000000000000000001730173017301730203020302030203021302130213021300027900267841515150000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280010000000280010000000280010000020
260007464616011007464816011009005321011009005621011010041621011010041821011013574026011013574226011014564729011014564929011018343318021018343618021020035418021020035618021022583818021022584018021005474302031005474502031010311305031010311505031011265308031011265508031011265508031011274108031021524009
0310215242090310060151130310063110130310160022210310160024210310022837280310022839280310                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        00206377740002484841000029844400181529330003034081000000000000000000
```

The problem happens with the spaces that start in the third line and goes to the fourth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I just ran a little test. Repositioning the BaseStream doesn't work for a TextReader, so you are simply reading from another position than you think you are (and are checking in the Watch window).

To solve it, you will have to create a new StreamReader for each property, and be careful *not* to close it (don't use a using block).

But I would go for reading it all at once (it is all text, right?) and operate on the string(s).

Comment: Altough I've not used your solution, your test made me think about calling reader.DiscardBufferedData(), and that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your problem is the `Encoding.ASCII`.  Are you positive your file is encoded this way?  I'd wager your file is actually encoded with `Encoding.Unicode`, which is why you're encountering zeroes.

In this case you say your encoding is UTF-8, so set your encoding to `Encoding.UTF8` and see what happens.

Comment: Or use `Encoding.Default` which is the default encoding on your windows system (not the default for `StreamReader` as one could easily think...)

Comment: It didn't work. The file is UTF-8. But changing that doesn't solves the problem.